# Benefits of using `Hash#fetch` over `Hash#[]`

Tags: ruby, hash

I am not sure in what situation I would want to use `Hash#fetch` over `Hash#[]`. Is there a common scenario in where it would be of good use?

Comment: Compare [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) and [Hash#\[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D). Now, can *you* think of some benefits? :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Three main uses:

1. When the value is mandatory, i.e. there is no default:

   ```
   options.fetch(:repeat).times{...}
   ```

   You get a nice error message too:

   ```
   key not found: :repeat
   ```
2. When the value can be `nil` or `false` and the default is something else:

   ```
   if (doit = options.fetch(:repeat, 1))
     doit.times{...}
   else
     # options[:repeat] is set to nil or false, do something else maybe
   end
   ```
3. When you don't want to use the `default`/`default_proc` of a hash:

   ```
   options = Hash.new(42)
   options[:foo] || :default # => 42
   options.fetch(:foo, :default) # => :default
   ```

Answer (score 6):

When you want to get a default value or raise an error when the key does not exist, `fetch` is useful. It is still possible to do so without `fetch` by setting the default value to the hash, but using `fetch`, you can do it on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can do this:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr[1..-2] #=> [1,2]
```

But not this:

```
arr.fetch(1..-2) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Range into Integer
```

Similarly you can mutate an array with `Hash#[]`

```
arr[0] = "A"
arr #=> ["A",2,3]
```

But not with fetch:

```
arr.fetch(0) = "A" #=> unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: I am new to Ruby, but [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) suggests that `#[]` and `#[]=` are considered separate methods. Otherwise `#[]` would have to be returning something like a reference to the selected element.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about `Hash`, not `Array`.